# Highcharts: draw a chart given a sequence of timestamps

Tags: highcharts

With Highcharts, is it possible to draw a chart representing the evolution over time of the frequency of an event, given the sequence of timestamps of the event's occurences ?

Of course, such a chart would depend on the "step" of the x-axis.

Is my question clear ?

Comment: yes it's possible, and no your question is not clear

Comment: Yah its possible, here is demo for zoomable and flexible chart with datetime time stamp http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series

Comment: it is possible and you need to show what you have done so far so we can help it out where you are actually stuck.

Comment: @Sameer are you sure, even with the details I gave in answer to strikers ?

Comment: @Arnaud yah i used to give answer if i am sure.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible
here is a working example for it http://jsfiddle.net/vJRB5/

for this to happen the xAxis type should be datetime

```
xAxis:{
  type: 'datetime'
}
```

You can pass timestamp directly or you can pass the date in UTC format as well

hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you but the problem with that is that you should put a value with every timestamp. I have only timestamps. Obviously, I could group them manually (for example, group all timestamps that are in the same month) and count the number of timestamps in every group, but I would like that Highcharts does this automatically, given the step of the x-axis (for example, a month). Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Please familair with demos which are published on http://www.highcharts.com

Comment: I've runned through these demos, but I haven't found a solution yet.